# Wrong classes with my class names

Tags: java, android, import

I've been going nuts with this for hours now and don't really know how to phrase what the problem is for an effective Google search, so here is a screenshot: 
[image]

So somehow Android Studio is fine with using the type `LevelCount`, but it seems to be a ghost type, and not the type I declared. When I try to force is to declare a new `LevelCount` (as I have defined it), it prefixes the package name instead of finding it directly.

In the screenshot, when I try `w.` the only methods that appear are `Object` methods, and none of my `LevelCount` methods. 
Any idea what is going on? 
I tried using Integer and had the same issue.

Comment: Check your imports, maybe you have two classes named `LevelCount` imported.

Comment: It sounds like the LevelCount class exists in more that one package which is ambiguous unless the full class name is specified.  It is also possible that you are missing an import statement at the top of your source file for the package that contains the LevelCount class you intend to use.